# WildFly randomly fails to load module when starting

Tags: wildfly

Using WildFly 14.0.1 in standalone mode within a Windows-based Docker container it randomly fails to start. It complains about different modules, but sometimes runs correctly. More often than not it fails.

The error reported generally is between loading the following modules:
* org.wildfly.extension.batch.jberet
* org.wildfly.extension.elytron
* org.wildfly.extension.bean-validation
* org.wildfly.extension.messaging-activemq
* org.wildfly.extension.request-controller

And in multiple executions to get this list it worked correctly once.

I've tried essentially the same setup on my host computer, using the same configuration files and it works reliably.

An example error:

```
10:38:40,597 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (Controller Boot Thread) OPVDX002: Failed to pretty print validation error: null
10:38:40,597 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0055: Caught exception during boot: org.jboss.as.controller.persistence.ConfigurationPersistenceException: WFLYCTL0085: Failed to parse configuration
        at org.jboss.as.controller.persistence.XmlConfigurationPersister.load(XmlConfigurationPersister.java:143)
        at org.jboss.as.server.ServerService.boot(ServerService.java:377)
        at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractControllerService$1.run(AbstractControllerService.java:372)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: WFLYCTL0083: Failed to load module org.wildfly.extension.batch.jberet
        at org.jboss.as.controller.parsing.DeferredExtensionContext.load(DeferredExtensionContext.java:100)
        at org.jboss.as.server.parsing.StandaloneXml_8.readServerElement(StandaloneXml_8.java:237)
        at org.jboss.as.server.parsing.StandaloneXml_8.readElement(StandaloneXml_8.java:137)
        at org.jboss.as.server.parsing.StandaloneXml.readElement(StandaloneXml.java:120)
        at org.jboss.as.server.parsing.StandaloneXml.readElement(StandaloneXml.java:52)
        at org.jboss.staxmapper.XMLMapperImpl.processNested(XMLMapperImpl.java:122)
        at org.jboss.staxmapper.XMLMapperImpl.parseDocument(XMLMapperImpl.java:76)
        at org.jboss.as.controller.persistence.XmlConfigurationPersister.load(XmlConfigurationPersister.java:126)
        ... 3 more
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: WFLYCTL0083: Failed to load module
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
        at org.jboss.as.controller.parsing.DeferredExtensionContext.load(DeferredExtensionContext.java:92)
        ... 10 more
Caused by: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: WFLYCTL0083: Failed to load module
        at org.jboss.as.controller.parsing.DeferredExtensionContext.loadModule(DeferredExtensionContext.java:129)
        at org.jboss.as.controller.parsing.DeferredExtensionContext.access$000(DeferredExtensionContext.java:44)
        at org.jboss.as.controller.parsing.DeferredExtensionContext$1.call(DeferredExtensionContext.java:74)
        at org.jboss.as.controller.parsing.DeferredExtensionContext$1.call(DeferredExtensionContext.java:71)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
        at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1985)
        at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1487)
        at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1349)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
        at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:485)
Caused by: org.jboss.modules.ModuleNotFoundException: org.wildfly.extension.batch.jberet
        at org.jboss.modules.ModuleLoader.loadModule(ModuleLoader.java:294)
        at org.jboss.modules.ModuleLoader.loadModule(ModuleLoader.java:280)
        at org.jboss.as.controller.parsing.DeferredExtensionContext.loadModule(DeferredExtensionContext.java:111)
        ... 10 more
```

When it does work, it begins to deploy the applications waiting in the deployments directory and starts up correctly.

Comment: Are you using the zip and extracting it?

Comment: Yes I am. I'm using the Expand-Archive tool in PowerShell.

Comment: That seems odd. It looks like it might not be fully extracting the content or possibly the file can't be read for some reason.